# Create a new instance of entity object out of form result - Symfony 5

Tags: php, symfony

I have three entities. 'Bordereau', 'Stagiaire', 'BordereauStagiaire'.

I've created a multistep form where to create a new Bordereau I need to show selected 'Stagiaires' to the user and then validate it. Bordereau and Stagiaire are both linked by the table BordereauStagiaire.

I managed to get both Bordereau and Stagiaire id in the controller through the form of a new Bordereau. But I'm looking for a means to create a new BordereauStagiaire when creating the new Bordereau.

This is the method I've started to implement. Backend, The Bordereau will be created first then the BS will be created with the new Bordereau and the selected stagiaires.BS table has the Bordereau id, Stagiaire id, and amount (another property).

How do I create a new BordereauStagiaire with the id of the Bordereau and those of the Stagiaires I got from the form?

This is my controller

```php
#[Route('/create/bordereau', name: 'app_bordereau_create', methods: ['GET','POST'])]
    public function createBordereauAction(CreateBordereauFlow $flow, PersistenceManagerRegistry $doctrine)
    {
        $formBordereau = new Bordereau();
        $formBordStag = new BordereauStagiaire();

        $formBordereau->setUser($this->getUser());

        $flow->bind($formBordereau);

        $form = $flow->createForm();
        
        if ($flow->isValid($form)) {
            $flow->getCurrentStepNumber($form);
            $flow->saveCurrentStepData($form);
            if ($flow->nextStep()) {
                $form = $flow->createForm();
                $flow->getCurrentStepNumber($form);
                $flow->saveCurrentStepData($form);
                // dd($form['stagiaire']->getData()[0]->getId());
                // dd($form->getData());
                
            } else{
                
                $entityManager = $doctrine->getManager();
                $entityManager->persist($formBordereau);
                $entityManager->flush();
                // dd($formBordereau->getId());
                return $this->redirectToRoute('app_bordereau_index');
                
            }
        }

        // if ($flow->redirectAfterSubmit($form)) {
        //     // $request = $this->getRequest();
        //     $params = $this->formFlowUtil->addRouteParameters(array_merge($request->query->all(),
        //             $request->attributes->get('_route_params')), $flow);
    
        //     return $this->redirectToRoute($request->attributes->get('_route'), $params);
        // }

        return $this->render('bordereau/create_bordereau.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'flow' => $flow,
            'formBordereau' =>$formBordereau,
        ]);
    }
```

This is how I get data from the Form `php $form['stagiaire']->getData()[0]->getId()` and bordereau I get its id after the persist and flush in the database. `php $formBordereau->getId()`

Answer (score 0):

I write as an anwer but it's more a comment with a lot of text.

Firstly, I would advice you to name your variables only in english, at least to avoid to name action names like `create` with `bordereau`.

Then, name your variable for what you will use them: `$formBordereau` is not a form, it an entity, you should use just `$bordereau`.

Then, do you need this entity `BordereauStagiaire` ? I understand it's a `ManyToMany` relation, Symfony & Doctrine manage it through entities directly, you don't need this 3rd entity.

Doctrine is an ORM, this means you work only with objects instead of IDs, if you design correctly your relations, you should have a method `addStagiaire` in your `Bordereau` entity, and vice-versa.

Then you should call this method with objects like:

```
// I am not sure here, does it return a Stagiaire Entity ? 
// I don't understand your flow form
$stagiaire = $form['stagiaire']->getData()[0];

$entityManager->persist($bordereau);
$bordereau->addStagiaire($stagiaire);
$entityManager->flush();
```